# How to group by and order By datetime Cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Hi how do I group by and order by a datetime field with CakePHP?

Answer (score 10):

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'order' => array('Post.date' => 'DESC'),
    'group' => 'Post.date'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already make an attempt and did it fail?

I don't have a CakePHP installation around to verify, but my first guess would be to state in the controller:

> `$this->Model->find("all", array('order'=>'Model.datetimeFieldName'));`

I'd expect Cake to handle the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Model->find(
        'all',
        array(
            'order' => array('Model.fieldname DESC');
            'group' => array('Model.fieldname');
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->Model->find('all',array('order'=>array('Model.fieldname'=>'DESC'),'group'=>array('Model.fieldname')));